# Reuse a view getting data from a different repository

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection

I have a UIVIewController with a collection View and a custom cell showing some data form an API endpoint.

This data is retrieve from this code:

```
private func getItems() {
        self.ItemsStartFetch(Text: "Fetching rooms", noItems: noRoomsViewContainer, itemsViewer: collectionContainer)

        let roomsController: RoomsController = RoomsController()
        roomsController.GetRooms { (status, items) in
            // Start Legacy Code
            RoomsController.rooms = items
            // End Legacy Code
            self.items = items
        self.ItemsRetrieved(noItemsView: self.noRoomsViewContainer, itemsViewer: self.collectionContainer , showViewer: (items.count > 0))
        self.roomCollection.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Now i need to create an exact same view where the difference will be retrieving the data from another endpoint, with the same estructure, but this time it comes from

```
private func getItems() {
        self.ItemsStartFetch(Text: "Fetching designs", noItems: noDesignsViewContainer, itemsViewer: collectionContainer)


    let designsController: DesignsController = DesignsController()
    designsController.GetDesigns { (status, items) in
        // Start Legacy Code
        DesignsController.Designs = items
        // End Legacy Code
        self.items = items
        self.ItemsRetrieved(noItemsView: self.noDesignsViewContainer, itemsViewer: self.collectionContainer , showViewer: (items.count > 0))
        self.designsCollection.reloadData()
    }
}
```

How can I inject into the UIViewConroller the controller to use?

Comment: The view is exactly the same; That is why I want to reuse it. The only difference is one time it needs to show designs and the other rooms. The designs data is fetched using the designs controller and the rooms with rooms controller. The rest of the UIVIewController is the same. If you look to the previous code the only difference is the controller name

Comment: Never mind, found my answer: https://cocoacasts.com/nuts-and-bolts-of-dependency-injection-in-swift

Comment: Personally I don't see what you think that article has to do with what you asked, but if you do, that's great. If the question is answered, please delete it or answer it.